# open file and read form it to buffer in assembly

Tags: file, assembly, x86, dos

hey im a beginner in assembly ,, i wont to open a file and read value " integer "
 from it and save the integer in buffer to print on the screen this is my code it doesn't work

```
include inout.asm
.model small,c
.486
.stack
.data
org 100h ; .com memory layout 
buf db ?
file db "c:\rtasm\bin\file.txt";the file name in bin
.code

mov dx, offset file ; address of file to dx 
mov al,0 ; open file (read-only) 
mov ah,3dh 
int 21h ; call the interupt 
mov bx,ax ; put handler to file in bx 


mov ah,40h
mov bx,ax
mov cx,2h                 ;; how many bytes you want to read
mov dx,offset buf  ;; where you want to store that data (see note on Offset above)
int 21h

call putchar,offset buf; print char on the screen


mov ah,3eh
mov bx,ax
int 21h 
.exit
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Int 21h function 3Dh ("OPEN EXISTING FILE") [expects a zero-terminated string](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2779.htm) in `ds:dx`. The string you're supplying doesn't have a zero terminator. The filename should be declared as `file db "c:\rtasm\bin\file.txt",0`.

Both function 3Dh and 40h return error codes if they fail. You should check for these and inform the user (yourself in this case) if an error has occurred, rather than assuming that the operations always will succeed.

Another problem is the following code:

```
mov bx,ax ; put handler to file in bx 

mov ah,40h      
mov bx,ax    <-- gives you a nonsense file handle since ah now is 40h
mov cx,2h          ;; how many bytes you want to read
mov dx,offset buf  ;; where you want to store that data (see note on Offset above)
int 21h
```

The second `mov bx,ax` is unnecessary since `bx` already contains the file handle. In fact, it's not only unnecessary but also incorrect since you've overwritten the high part of `ax` (`ah`) with the value 40h.
There's also the fact that you're reading two bytes into a buffer that only has room for one byte.

Comment: what the file handle ?  
   mov     bx, FHndl       ;Get file handle value

Comment: What about it? There's no such line in the code you posted in your question.

Comment: not in my code  but i read that on many site .... like this 

     mov     FHndl, ax       ;Save file handle
LP:             mov     ah,3fh          ;Read data from the file
                lea     dx, Buffer      ;Address of data buffer
                mov     cx, 1           ;Read one byte
                mov     bx, FHndl       ;Get file handle value
                int     21h
           handle is db (buffer)

Comment: You can store it in any suitable place if you need to save it for later. You seem to rely on `ax` maintaining its value even though you change part of the `ax` register, or call interrupt functions that modify `ax`. That's obviously not going to work, so I suggest that you read up on how registers work and study the interrupts you're using more carefully.

Comment: I am accepting a cmd-line parameter which, of course is not zero-terminated. How do I get the parameter zero-terminated?

Comment: IAbstract: If you have a question of your own you should post it as such.